# Find the number of distinct 6-tuples of integers with constant sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) How many distinct 6-tuples of positive integers (a1,...,a6) are there such that a1+...+a6 = 14?

(b) How many distinct 6-tuples of nonnegative integers (a1,...,a6) are there such that a1+...+a6 = 14?

I'm thinking the only difference between (a) and (b) is that 0 is not allowed in (a)

Comment: You are correct about the difference between (a) and (b). (b) is a standard stars and bars problem. For (a), simply set the condition beforehand that each of $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{6}$ is at least $1$. Then, the problem is a standard stars and bars problem of distributing $8$ apples to 6 people, allowing a person to receive $0$ apples.

Comment: That is correct.  Have you looked at [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?

Comment: Thanks, looking into stars and bars now.